# css transition choppy in iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I've been tasked with creating a 3 image slide show to be placed on the front page of an advertiser's website.  As such, I've created a page with the css embedded, then I've created a code snippet (just an iframe) to target the page which will be given to the advertiser to put on their page.

The page source code (AD.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.AD-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
}
.AD-img img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.AD-img img:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fading2 ease 14s infinite;  
  animation: fading2 ease 14s infinite;
}
.AD-img img:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fading3 ease 14s infinite;  
  animation: fading3 ease 14s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fading2 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  21% { opacity: 0;}
  35% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fading2 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  21% { opacity: 0;}
  35% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fading3 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  56% { opacity: 0;}
  70% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fading3 {
  0%: { opacity: 0;}
  56% { opacity: 0;}
  70% { opacity: 1;}
  93% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
</style>
</head>
</body>
<div class="AD-img">
   <img width="300px" height="250px" src="1.jpg">
   <img width="300px" height="250px" src="2.jpg">
   <img width="300px" height="250px" src="3.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To test the iframe, I made a this small page and put it in the same directory.  We'll call it index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
</body>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://www.example.com/ADdirectory/AD.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The images and pages are being hosted on my server, not the advertisers
(I've changed the domain name and such to generic equivalents for privacy sake).

Everything works fine in chrome, but if I view index.html in firefox the transition is very choppy.  Oddly enough, firefox works fine if I view the AD.html page directly.

To add to the headache, neither works at all in IE9 (why can't everyone just use chrome :p).

I'm very new to css, so I hope it's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: I've officially thrown my hands up in the air and just did it with js (not with the fade effect though).  Still, I'd like to know why this is happening.